# SDN 4 Gradle Setup

Tags: groovy, gradle, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I'm trying to get SDN 4 working with Gradle and Groovy and having checked other posts on here I got it working the other night but I guess something has changed over the last couple of days.

When I try and run the tests it fails because of `ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.ogm.testutil.TestServer` and I when I check the dependencies I cannot find the neo4j-ogm test jar.

I've tried various combinations of neo4j-ogm and neo4j-ogm-test and versions from 1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT to 1.1.1 without any luck.

It would be fantastic if someone could could point me in the right direction as I can't see the wood for the trees right now.

The project can be found [here](https://github.com/ricfeatherstone/sdn-gradle).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In recent snapshots, the OGM has been split from SDN, as such the test utilities have to be included explicitly-

```
 testCompile 'org.neo4j.test:neo4j-harness:2.2.2'
 testCompile 'org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm:1.1.0:tests'
```

You can drop `testCompile 'org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-test:1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:tests'`